# How to Auto Fit Excel Columns in MVC-4 ActionResult before returning EXCEL File?

Tags: c#, excel, model-view-controller, actionresult

> Following is the ActionResult Method created to return EXCEl File, which works fine. However, there is a problem that the content for each column is too large that the rows are mal-formed, which means there are wide blank-spaces between rows. 
>   Following is the ActionResult code.

```
public ActionResult ImportExecelFile(int appNo)
{

        List<PendingApproval> pendings = objPA.GetPendingApprovals(appNo.ToString());

        string xml = String.Empty;
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(pendings.GetType());

        using (MemoryStream xmlStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlStream, pendings);
            xmlStream.Position = 0;
            xmlDoc.Load(xmlStream);
            xml = xmlDoc.InnerXml;
        }

        //Create file
        string fileName = "Pending_Approvals";

        fileName += string.Format("-{0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
        fileName += ".xls";

        byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);

        return File(fileContents, "application/vnd.ms-excel", fileName);          
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not creating an Excel file - you're creating XML and saving it with an .xls extension. Excel will try its best to open it, although it's probably going to raise a warning to the user because it's not really an Excel file.

Excel files can contain formatting, including column widths. Data serialized as XML will not have that. So there's really no way to control how Excel displays the XML.

You can accomplish what you're trying to do using a library like [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) that creates Excel workbooks using OpenXML. But if you're just saving XML as .xls then you won't have any control over formatting. (I'm amazed it opens at all, but I tested saving an XML file as .xls and it worked except for the warning message.)